# Pull Text Body from a previous Email into new Reminder Notification

Tags: email-template, email2case, case-object, process-automation

i am trying to understand if its possible to create an Case follow up Reminder Email Notification (Case Object) which pulls the previous email sent by a customer and stamps that into the new email body. Very similar to how Salesforce Case reminder emails are sent providing the end user context in the reminder.

Scenario: 5 days after a Case email has not been responded to we have a "Reminder" email sent out to the customer to gently nudge them from a No-Reply address. They often have many Cases open and are not aware which one they need to respond back to. We already have the Description Subject included, but we were curious how custom it would be to include the last email sent from the "WebEmail" on the Case record? Has anyone implemented something like this before?

Comment: You'd be able to use a Record-Triggered Flow with a time delayed path to achieve this, as long as you can control when you want the reminder sent based on the Case values. In the flow you'd be able to retrieve any related records (like emails) and then construct the body of the email you are sending.

Comment: Thanks @CallumMacErlich for your response. Would this be EmailMessage object that I would be able to use a get element in the flow? I think i kind of have an idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Yep that is correct. As a heads up, there are two different fields on EmailMessage that store the body of the email that's been sent, HTMLBody and TextBody, so you'll need to make sure you use the right one.

Comment: Awesome thank you @callum really appreciate the input here!